# Show/Display file content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table showing file location along with other informations. for e.g. :

[image]

When the user click on the first row i.e. on `$_FILES` then it should display the contents of `FileA.txt`. 
Is it possible to do this using javascript or using Angular js?

I don't want to use

```
<input type='file' />
```

as we already know the file location and also it gives dialog box which ask to save the file, I don't want this. Instead I directly want to show file content. But as I said it shows dialog box which I don't want to show hence looking for alternative.

Thanks in advance,

Ramesh

Comment: Not possible in javascript. With ajax it is possible to display the contents of the file on the server

Comment: you could use php for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mjzAU/2/

Comment: @DeepKakkar i have already done this. Just want to do the same but without the browse button as i already have the file location

Comment: use ajax for that. that is why I have deleted my answer

Comment: so ajax is only option to view local file as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using php:

```
<?php 
   $filepath = "yourpathhere";
   $content = file_get_contents($filepath);
   echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: I have some .txt files that have news articles saved in them that are formatted with html tags, so I use this to render articles on their respective pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to give file location as `id` of corresponding `<tr>`. `file_class` is class of table.
and create a div with class `text` in which file content will be displayed.
JQuery Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".file_class").click(function() {
var file_location = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url : encodeURIComponent(file_location),
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".text").html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML Code should be like this:

```
<table class="file_class"><tr id="D:\input.txt"></tr></table>
```

Comment: I have set table tag as <table id="D:\input.txt" class="file_class"> but success function is not hit hence text div is not filled.

Comment: I have already tried that but file_location is 'undefined' and 'data' obtained is the content of the html file hence shows the same table

Comment: check firebug what request is going and response. check <tr> tag I have given id of <tr> as file location

Comment: setting url: "D:\\input.txt"  gives 'Invalid argument' error as for details will check firebug as you mentioned

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent() once. you have to encode the string. please comment success or unsuccess.

Comment: This is helpful to view content of file exist in the web server but i need to view content of local file or shared file. Is it possible to view those content or not? OR we have to upload the file to web server to view which i don't want to do.